# Is there a solution to this formula stopping an AutoSort script

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am attempting to learn to script as I develop a project so please forgive me if I ask this question incorrectly.

I have created an AutoSort script for a google sheets document to sort a list of players by "Weight".  It works fine until I add the following formula.  Once I add this formula, my data is to be sorted by Column 7, largest to smallest and doesn't completely.  The odd part of this is that the players that are out of order are listed as Substitutes.

The way this sheet works.  
The Match Tool tab is where players are selected from Data Validation cells.  
The Data Validation list comes from the MR1 Tab.  
The MR1 tab gets it list based on an importrange defined in the MRTool.

This comes from a larger document and I've extracted the vital parts to make the error happen.  I've tried to run a bare-bones version with only text and the AutoSort script and it sorts correctly.  I have also tried changing which column the AutoSort looks in and it works correctly.

The formula that stops the script from working:

`=if(or(C10="",C10=". Blank"),"",iferror(index('MR1'!$B$8:$H$87,(match(C10,'MR1'!$N$8:$N$87,0))),"Player Not Found"))`

The Script for the AutoSort:

```
  var roster = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Match Tool");
  var range1 = roster.getRange("B10:K59");
  var range2 = roster.getRange("N10:W59");

  range1.sort( [{ column : 7, ascending: false}, { column : 11, ascending: false}] );
  range2.sort( [{ column : 19, ascending: false}, { column : 23, ascending: false}] );
 }

function SortLeft() {

  var roster = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Match Tool");
  var range1 = roster.getRange("B10:K59");

  range1.sort( [{ column : 7, ascending: false}, { column : 11, ascending: false}] );
 }

function SortRight() {

  var roster = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Match Tool");
  var range2 = roster.getRange("N10:W59");

  // It seems that column numbers are always sequential from the first one, even if you are addressing a range. Hence using 14/18 here instead of 4/8

  range2.sort( [{ column : 19, ascending: false}, { column : 23, ascending: false}] );
 }

function SortSelection() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var firstcol = range.getColumn();
  var lastcol = range.getLastColumn();

  //Before sorting, this code checks to make sure that Clan through Combined heroes is selected on one side or the other. If not, an error appears.

  if (firstcol == 2 && lastcol == 11 ) {  range.sort( [{ column : 7, ascending: false}, { column : 11, ascending: false}] )} //&& lastcol == 11
  else if ( firstcol == 14 && lastcol == 23 ) { range.sort( [{ column : 19, ascending: false}, { column : 23, ascending: false}] )} //&& lastcol == 23 
  else { SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('You can only sort selections that include all 8 data columns, from Clan to Notes.');}
 }

function onEdit(e){

  var roster = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Match Tool");
  var autosort = roster.getRange(6, 13).getValue();
  var range1 = roster.getRange("B10:K59");
  var range2 = roster.getRange("N10:W59");

 //  if('B3' === GWL) {
//     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('K2').setValue('40');          
//   }

   // test if K2 (war size) was modified
  if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() == "Match Tool" && e.range.rowStart === 6 && e.range.columnStart === 13) {
    moveToSub();
  }
  //preform autosort if on
  if ( autosort == "On" ){
  range1.sort( [{ column : 7, ascending: false}, { column : 11, ascending: false}] );
  range2.sort( [{ column : 19, ascending: false}, { column : 23, ascending: false}] );
  }  
  }
```

I expect players to be sorted by column 7 (column G) descending and then column 11 (Column K) descending. What I'm getting is certain players not sorted correctly.  
I am getting   -  132, 131, 131, 113, 111, **132**, **113**, 90, 88, 87, 86.  
I should see   -  **132**, 132, 131, 131, **113**, 113, 111, 90, 88, 87, 86.  
  
Thank you for taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 0):

After some help from a friend, we realized the problem wasn't anything to do with the script on this page, it was how the data was entered on the sheet the data was imported in from.  Some numbers were entered as numerals while others were entered in as text.  By changing the text to numerals, the script performed as expected.

So the moral of the story is, check to make sure the data being sort is of the same type.